# Safe and cheap expansion of names of a factor variable in formula

Tags: r

I would like to get the expanded names of a factor variable in a formula evaluated against an environment, if the unexpanded name is in a vector of names that I provide. 
This should be seamless even if the name that I provide appears  in the formula inside an operator such as `as.factor`.

A couple of examples to illustrate what I want:

#### Example 1:

```
data(iris)
lmIris = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + 
              Petal.Width + Species,  data = iris)

namesFactorExpansion = 
  paste0('Species', levels(iris$Species), sep = '')
namesFactorExpansion
```

The output is

> [1] "Speciessetosa"     "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica"

#### Example 2:

```
data(airquality)
lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + as.factor(Month), 
   data = airquality)
namesFactorExpansion = 
  paste0('as.factor(Month)', levels(as.factor(airquality$Month)), sep = '')
namesFactorExpansion
```

The output in this case is

> [1] "as.factor(Month)5" "as.factor(Month)6" "as.factor(Month)7"  
>   [4] "as.factor(Month)8" "as.factor(Month)9"

Note the different handling I have to do to accommodate the `as.factor` in the formula.

**Motivation:** I am already making a call to `model.frame` in the function that I am writing. I need this variable name expansion to deal with a different formal argument of my function that takes variable names, without a second call to `model.frame`.

So, to give a simplified example, here is a function that accepts a formula, a dataset, and a vector of variable names, and should be able to return the same output as above.

```
fnGetFactorExpansion = function(formula, data, partial) {
  # FUN STUFF GOES HERE
}

fnGetFactorExpansion(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + 
                       Petal.Width + Species,  data = iris,
                     partial = 'Species')
## [1] "Speciessetosa"     "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica" 

fnGetFactorExpansion(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + as.factor(Month), 
                     data = airquality,
                     partial = 'Month')
## [1] "as.factor(Month)5" "as.factor(Month)6" "as.factor(Month)7"
## [4] "as.factor(Month)8" "as.factor(Month)9"
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there a function or package that does this?
2. Is there a seamless way to handle this without having to do explicit case management?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to ask.  Please give the desired output.

Comment: @fgnu It isn't entirely clear why you are generating these names. In general, you can run the model and then retrieve them afterwards using `names(coefficients(my_model))`.  Your question makes it sound like this isn't an option though, so I'm intrigued about your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Since these names are created by `lm` (forming the names of the coefficients), I used `debug(lm)` and stepped through to see where they are created.  It's on the line

```
x <- model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
```

so then I stepped through `model.matrix.default`, which led me to the line

```
ans <- .Internal(model.matrix(t, data))
```

So the names are set in C code.  A quick internet search with Google for

```
site:https://svn.r-project.org/R filetype:c model.matrix
```

finds this file

```
http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/model.c
```

Searching within this file for "names" led me to the logic where names are populated.  You want the loop after the line

```
SET_STRING_ELT(xnames, k++, mkChar("(Intercept)"));
```

---

Of course, reusing the C code directly is more trouble than it's worth, so I suggest trying to call the R level `model.matrix` to generate the names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function:

```
fnGetFactorExpansion <- function(form, dat, partial) {
  idx <- partial == all.vars(form[[3]])
  term <- attr(terms(form), "term.labels")[idx]
  newForm <- reformulate(term, intercept = FALSE)
  mat <- model.matrix(newForm, dat)
  nam <- colnames(mat)
  return(nam)
}
```

The function does not manipulate or create strings. All operations are based on the formula terms.

Examples:

```
fnGetFactorExpansion(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + 
                       Petal.Width + Species,  dat = iris,
                     partial = 'Species')
# [1] "Speciessetosa"     "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica" 


fnGetFactorExpansion(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + as.factor(Month), 
                     dat = airquality,
                     partial = 'Month')
# [1] "as.factor(Month)5" "as.factor(Month)6" "as.factor(Month)7"
# [4] "as.factor(Month)8" "as.factor(Month)9"
```

Comment: In particular, this will continue to work if the underlying C code changes.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
fnGetFactorExpansion <- function(formula, data, partial){
    x <- strsplit(as.character(formula)[3],"\\s+\\+\\s+")[[1]]
    varname <- grep(partial,x,value=TRUE)
    paste0(varname,sort(unique(data[[partial]])))
    }

fnGetFactorExpansion(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + 
                     Petal.Width + Species,  data = iris,
                     partial = 'Species')
[1] "Speciessetosa"     "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica" 

fnGetFactorExpansion(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + as.factor(Month), 
                     data = airquality,
                     partial = 'Month')
[1] "as.factor(Month)5" "as.factor(Month)6" "as.factor(Month)7"
[4] "as.factor(Month)8" "as.factor(Month)9"
```